# slapd uses too much CPU using Drupal 7 with simple_ldap module

Tags: drupal-7, openldap

We configured a Drupal 7 instance with [simple_ldap](https://drupal.org/project/simple_ldap) module pointing to a local OpenLDAP (on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS server).

When multiple users log in to the site, and use it, the CPU of the computer goes wild : `slapd` is using nearly 100% of the CPU.

The result is that the Drupal site answers so slowly (more than 15s a page...)

In `/var/log/syslog` we can see that :

```
Feb 20 14:56:53 cas slapd[2029]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (uid) not indexed
Feb 20 14:56:53 cas slapd[2029]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (mail) not indexed
Feb 20 14:56:53 cas slapd[2029]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (member) not indexed
Feb 20 14:56:53 cas slapd[2029]: <= bdb_equality_candidates: (cn) not indexed
```

What's going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had to create the correct index for that.

As [said here](http://yourlinuxadmin.blogspot.fr/2013/05/bdbequalitycandidates-uid-not-indexed.html), first stop the service :

```
sudo service slapd stop
```

Then edit `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif` and add (just after line `olcDbIndex: objectClass eq`) :

```
...
olcDbIndex: uid eq
olcDbIndex: member eq
olcDbIndex: mail eq
olcDbIndex: cn eq
...
```

Then re-index, set the correct rights and restart the service :

```
sudo slapindex -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d
sudo chown -R openldap:openldap /var/lib/ldap
sudo service slapd start
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: It's recommended to use the right user for reindexing: "sudo -u openldap slapindex", so you can avoid the chown

Comment: Also, note that with this method you have to manually adjust the CRC inside {1}hdb.ldif